# Verificar valores dentro de um JSON

Tags: javascript, json, array

Em JavaScript estou pegando um JSON assim:

```
function checaEad(){
    var urlEad = 'http://urljason.json';
    $.getJSON(urlEad, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Ele me retorna isso:

```
{"user_cpf":"111.111.111-11","user_name":"NOME","matriculas":{
    "357847":{"mat_id":357847,"id_curso":2129,"concluido":true},
    "358696":{"mat_id":358696,"id_curso":4738,"concluido":true},
    "362953":{"mat_id":362953,"id_curso":5041,"concluido":false}
}}
```

Agora não estou conseguindo tratar essa array.

Preciso checar se dentro da array que me retornaram existe o `id_curso = xxxx`, se existir, checar se `concluido =  true`.

Tentei algo assim:

```
data.includes('5041');
```

Mas fala que o token é inválido, não é para eu tratar igual se trata um array simples? Pois assim funciona:

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);     // true
```

Comment: Entender a [sintaxe do JSON](http://json.org/) é fundamental para saber manipulá-lo. Basicamente, se estiver delimitado por `{` e `}` é um objeto. Para ser um array, o delimitador deve ser `[` e `]`.

Comment: E complementando tbm, o objeto você vai acessar suas propriedades utilizando um **`.`** e no array geralmente através de um **índice**.

Comment: o seu checar é se o concluido é `== true` ou é para mudar o concluido para `=true` ??? fiquei nessa duvida?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse JSON não é uma array mas sim um Objeto. Concordo que `matriculas` podia/devia ser uma array... mas não é :)

Se precisares de verificar o estado do curso podes fazer assim:

```
function verificarCursoConcluido(id, data) {
  const curso = Object.keys(data.matriculas).find(matricula => {
    return dataAtualizada.matriculas[matricula].id_curso === id;
  });
  return curso && curso.concluido;
}
```

Caso queiras mudar podes fazer assim:

```js
const json = {
  "user_cpf": "111.111.111-11",
  "user_name": "NOME",
  "matriculas": {
    "357847": {
      "mat_id": 357847,
      "id_curso": 2129,
      "concluido": true
    },
    "358696": {
      "mat_id": 358696,
      "id_curso": 4738,
      "concluido": true
    },
    "362953": {
      "mat_id": 362953,
      "id_curso": 5041,
      "concluido": false
    }
  }
};

function concluir(curso, data) {
  const dataAtualizada = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  const concluido = Object.keys(dataAtualizada.matriculas).find(matricula => {
    return dataAtualizada.matriculas[matricula].id_curso === curso;
  });

  if (concluido) {
    dataAtualizada.matriculas[concluido].concluido = true;
  }
  return dataAtualizada;
}

const atualizado = concluir(5041, json);
console.log(atualizado);
```

A ideia é percorrer essas matriculas, e caso haja uma que tenha o `id_curso` procurado marcar como completo. A função que criei retorna uma nova cópia do objeto, mas podes retirar essa lógica se não precisares de uma lógica imutável.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou dar uma estudada agora que você me deu uma luz. Só uma coisa, se existir, tem como checar se concluído é igual a true?

Comment: @caiocafardo tudo é possível :) nesse caso bastam as primeiras linhas do código `const concluido = Object.keys(dataAtualizada.matriculas).find(matricula => { ...... });` e depois fazer `console.log(concluido. concluido);`

Comment: Eu não sei se ficou claro, o checar dele pode ter duplo sentido é checar de alterar o valor ou é checar de verificar o valor? @Sergio

Comment: De verificar, Também consegui, agora entendi a lógica!

Comment: @caiocafardo é só mostrar o que tem dentro de `concluido`?

Comment: @caiocafardo juntei um exemplo de função `verificarCursoConcluido`, mas acho que já encontraste a solução também.

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira simples, buscas as chaves desse `json` (que é um dicionário de valores) e após isso um interação até achar ou não o valor que foi perguntado e no final apresentar verdadeiro ou falso contido em `concluido`, ***exemplo***:

```js
var json = {"user_cpf":"111.111.111-11","user_name":"NOME","matriculas":{
    "357847":{"mat_id":357847,"id_curso":2129,"concluido":true},
    "358696":{"mat_id":358696,"id_curso":4738,"concluido":true},
    "362953":{"mat_id":362953,"id_curso":5041,"concluido":false}
}};

function busca_matricula_concluida(matriculas, id_curso)
{
    keys = Object.keys(matriculas);   
    i = 0;
    while(i < keys.length){
      if (matriculas[keys[i]].id_curso == id_curso){
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    return (i < keys.length) && (matriculas[keys[i]].concluido);
    
}

console.log(busca_matricula_concluida(json.matriculas, 4738));
console.log(busca_matricula_concluida(json.matriculas, 0));
```